# Send and not send a file using annotation Post on Jax-Rs

Tags: java, jax-rs

I´m developing a Jax-Rs service, and I have to create something with and without a file.

```
 @POST
    @Path("makesomething")
    @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
       public String makesomething(@FormDataParam("file") InputStream uploadedInputStream, @FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition fileDetail, @FormDataParam("variable") String variable, @Context HttpServletRequest request) throws IOException {
        //make something
        }
```

If I don´t send a file I receive an error message, saying that is necessary to send a file. How can I make this without sending a file?

Comment: Make a second `makesomething` method which does not have the file parameter...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

André is right, something like this should work just fine (assuming when you aren't uploading a file you are just posting form data):

```
@POST
@Path("makesomething")
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public String makesomething(@FormDataParam("file") InputStream uploadedInputStream, @FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition fileDetail, @FormDataParam("variable") String variable, @Context HttpServletRequest request) throws IOException {
    makeSomethingImpl(uploadedInputStream, fileDetail, variable, request);
}

@POST
@Path("makesomething")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public String makesomething(@FormDataParam("variable") String variable, @Context HttpServletRequest request) throws IOException {
    makeSomethingImpl(null, null, variable, request);
}

private String makeSomethingImpl(final InputStream uploadedInputStream, final FormDataContentDisposition fileDetail, final String variable, final HttpServletRequest request) {
    // make something
}
```